# Apache httpd.conf User/Group Setting

Tags: apache, webserver

I have an httpd.conf file that contains the following:

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
<If "env('OS') == 'Darwin'">
    User daemon
    Group admin
</If>
<Else>
    User www
    Group scm
</Else>
</IfModule>
```

What I'm trying to do is set the user id for the httpd instance in my development environment on OSX to one user, but a different user when it is deployed to Ubuntu.  I'm receiving a syntax error message:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 32 of /usr/local/apps/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
User not allowed here
```

I looked at the [If](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if) directive and it is allowed here.  If I comment out the User/Group I do not get the syntax error.  Without the IF/Else, and only using one user, this works.  If I try to use the condition with the user/group I receive an error.  Is this possible in the httpd.conf?  If so, then how?  Is there a different way to accomplish the same thing?  The "OS" environment variable is set in each environment with "export OS=`uname`".  This is in Apache httpd 2.4.4.

Comment: not sure about 2.4.4 but isn't there another way to achieve what you want? if in doubt, look in the source code how syntax check is performed, that's what I would do. Could be, that User/Group or If/Else are not supposed to be used toghether, or it is behaviour other than expected i.e. bug. I recall in Debian and previous apache versions there was another way, shell variables $APACHEUSER and $APACHEGROUP was used from calling script ( usually init.d script ), sourced from /etc/default/apache2 file. And the question probably should be moved to superuser.com , as it's not really programming rel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a moment to check it more deeply, and it is because Override behaviour. I have briefly checked with 2.4.4 source, and it seems to me, that basically only directives which are on "Override" list in current Directory or Location contexts are overridable with If/Else.

As "User" and "Group" are supposed to be set once for the whole installation, and not to be modified by ".htaccess" or depending on Directory/Location context, therefore they are not on some default "AllowOverride" list, and you cannot simply put it into such context to make them overridable. Makes sense though, to force User/Group options to be valid only on top of apache internal "configuration tree".

To achieve behaviour you need in reasonable way, as I explained shortly in my comment, you should use "envvars" mechanism, available by default in Debian ( probably Ubuntu as well ).

In short, there's /etc/apache2/envvars file containing e.g.

```
unset HOME
if [ "${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}" != "${APACHE_CONFDIR}" ] ; then
    SUFFIX="-${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}"
else
    SUFFIX=
fi
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
export LANG=C
export LANG
```

It is sourced/inherited by /etc/init.d/apache2 startup script, so in httpd main config file (e.g. apache2.conf) the following section can be used

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

Simple modification of /etc/apache2/envvars would then let you get what you need. You can also change some default value for User/Group in compile settings for User/Group used on your OSX, and use the script on Ubuntu side only.